# JSON with objects named "-1"

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am needing to grab some JSON from a site and parse it. The problem is that the objects are named "-1"  "-2" and so forth.

When I try to parse it, Firebug comes back with, "TypeError: obj is undefined
length = obj.length"

Chrome comes back with a similar message, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

For reference, here's a snipet of the JSON:

```
{
  "-1": {
     "number": 47,
     "properties": [
       [
```

And here's the code I'm trying to use.

```
$.getJSON("http://www.website.com/builds?select=-1&select=-10",function(data){
  $.each(data.-1, function(info,value){
```

If I download the JSON, save it locally and rename "-1" to "one", rename "-2" to "two", then it works fine. E.G. the JSON becomes:

```
{
  "one": {
     "number": 47,
     "properties": [
       [
```

And my code becomes

```
$.getJSON("C:\json.json",function(data){
    $.each(data.one, function(info,value){
```

This works fine, but it adds another complicated step.

Is there a way to parse on the original JSON (as it is generated automatically from a server, and changes often), or am I stuck with trying to figure out how to save it locally and change the object names before parsing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data.-1` must be referenced as a string using bracket notation.

`data["-1"]`